# Flag if a string is present in a select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check if there is a specific sequence of characters in a select and if so, indicate the case by setting a variable.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
    @FLAG = CASE 
                WHEN '%ABC%' IN (SELECT [COLUMN] 
                                 FROM [TABLE] 
                                 WHERE [CONDITION]) 
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0
```

but it doesn't work because the `@FLAG` result is always "0"

(the output of the SELECT is a list of rows)

Comment: You missed `LIKE OPERATOR` :)

Comment: You can't like multiple IN values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your criteria to use `EXISTS`, like

```
SELECT 
    @FLAG = CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT [COLUMN] 
                             FROM [TABLE] 
                             WHERE [CONDITION] AND [COLUMN] LIKE '%ABC%') 
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0
```

unless you are interested to find records where `[COLUMN]` is exactly `'%ABC%'`